# Как из сохранённого числа, полученного с помощью timestamp сформировать и вывести дату?

Tags: unixtimestamp, php

В базу данных при написании какого-нибудь поста в графу "дата" сохраняется число, полученное с помощью функции time(). Как в последствии сделать, чтобы из этого числа формировалась дата и выводилась в необходимом формате?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$timestamp_from_base)
```

Comment: Спасибо! думал, нельзя в качестве параметра вставлять просто число :)

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще и в запросе к базе сразу форматировать.

```
SELECT date_format(`date_field`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as `date_field` FROM `table`
```